# Query string web part query

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part

I have a query regarding the Query string web part. I have configured the web part and when I type the append the URL, it will fill the value into the designated column, which works perfectly.

However user can enter any text in the URL, which I want it to be restricted.

Is there anyway to achieve it? Or any other alternate suggestion?